# optaplanner incorrect cloud balance output

Tags: optaplanner

I am trying a simple Cloud balance example in the opta planner tutorial.

I have 2 computers and 4 process ( the same example which is explained in the opta planner documentation ).Each process needs certain amount of RAM and CPU .

The final solved output is incorrect which you can see from the logs below. Hard rules are violated.

Ideally Process 1 and 4 should fit in computer 1 .
Process 2 and 3 should fit in computer 2.

From the logs looks like HeuristicPhase happens but local search is not showing up in the logs.

Please guide me what I am dong wrong.

```
After building unsolvedCloudBalance  Computers [ Computer [C1][7 CPU][6 RAM],  Computer [C2][6 CPU][6 RAM]] Processes [ Process [P1][5 CPU][5 RAM],  Process [P2][4 CPU][3 RAM],  Process [P3][2 CPU][3 RAM],  Process [P4][2 CPU][1 RAM]] Hard Soft Score null
01:35:57.099 [main] INFO  o.o.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver - Solving started: time spent (3), best score (4uninitialized/0hard/0soft), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), random (JDK with seed 0).
01:35:57.099 [main] INFO  o.o.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver - Solving started: time spent (3), best score (4uninitialized/0hard/0soft), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), random (JDK with seed 0).
01:35:57.104 [main] DEBUG o.o.c.i.c.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase -     CH step (0), time spent (9), score (0hard/-800soft), selected move count (2), picked move ( Process [P1][5 CPU][5 RAM] {null ->  Computer [C2][6 CPU][6 RAM]}).
01:35:57.104 [main] DEBUG o.o.c.i.c.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase -     CH step (0), time spent (9), score (0hard/-800soft), selected move count (2), picked move ( Process [P1][5 CPU][5 RAM] {null ->  Computer [C2][6 CPU][6 RAM]}).
01:35:57.104 [main] DEBUG o.o.c.i.c.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase -     CH step (1), time spent (9), score (0hard/-1800soft), selected move count (2), picked move ( Process [P2][4 CPU][3 RAM] {null ->  Computer [C1][7 CPU][6 RAM]}).
01:35:57.104 [main] DEBUG o.o.c.i.c.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase -     CH step (1), time spent (9), score (0hard/-1800soft), selected move count (2), picked move ( Process [P2][4 CPU][3 RAM] {null ->  Computer [C1][7 CPU][6 RAM]}).
01:35:57.104 [main] DEBUG o.o.c.i.c.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase -     CH step (2), time spent (9), score (0hard/-1800soft), selected move count (1), picked move ( Process [P3][2 CPU][3 RAM] {null ->  Computer [C1][7 CPU][6 RAM]}).
01:35:57.104 [main] DEBUG o.o.c.i.c.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase -     CH step (2), time spent (9), score (0hard/-1800soft), selected move count (1), picked move ( Process [P3][2 CPU][3 RAM] {null ->  Computer [C1][7 CPU][6 RAM]}).
01:35:57.105 [main] DEBUG o.o.c.i.c.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase -     CH step (3), time spent (10), score (-1hard/-1800soft), selected move count (2), picked move ( Process [P4][2 CPU][1 RAM] {null ->  Computer [C2][6 CPU][6 RAM]}).
01:35:57.105 [main] DEBUG o.o.c.i.c.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase -     CH step (3), time spent (10), score (-1hard/-1800soft), selected move count (2), picked move ( Process [P4][2 CPU][1 RAM] {null ->  Computer [C2][6 CPU][6 RAM]}).
01:35:57.106 [main] INFO  o.o.c.i.c.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase - Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: step total (4), time spent (11), best score (-1hard/-1800soft).
01:35:57.106 [main] INFO  o.o.c.i.c.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase - Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: step total (4), time spent (11), best score (-1hard/-1800soft).
01:36:07.095 [main] DEBUG o.o.c.i.l.DefaultLocalSearchPhase -     LS step (0), time spent (10000), score (-2hard/-1800soft),     best score (-1hard/-1800soft), accepted/selected move count (0/9152031), picked move ( Process [P4][2 CPU][1 RAM] { Computer [C2][6 CPU][6 RAM] ->  Computer [C1][7 CPU][6 RAM]}).
01:36:07.095 [main] DEBUG o.o.c.i.l.DefaultLocalSearchPhase -     LS step (0), time spent (10000), score (-2hard/-1800soft),     best score (-1hard/-1800soft), accepted/selected move count (0/9152031), picked move ( Process [P4][2 CPU][1 RAM] { Computer [C2][6 CPU][6 RAM] ->  Computer [C1][7 CPU][6 RAM]}).
01:36:07.096 [main] INFO  o.o.c.i.l.DefaultLocalSearchPhase - Local Search phase (1) ended: step total (1), time spent (10001), best score (-1hard/-1800soft).
01:36:07.096 [main] INFO  o.o.c.i.l.DefaultLocalSearchPhase - Local Search phase (1) ended: step total (1), time spent (10001), best score (-1hard/-1800soft).
01:36:07.096 [main] INFO  o.o.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver - Solving ended: time spent (10001), best score (-1hard/-1800soft), average calculate count per second (915112), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE).
01:36:07.096 [main] INFO  o.o.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver - Solving ended: time spent (10001), best score (-1hard/-1800soft), average calculate count per second (915112), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE).
 time taken 10 sec
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked as expected after I added difficultyComparatorClass to the @PlanningEntity annotation.